# How to use route.params with stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass a parameter through route.params for a different screen. That parameter will be used to call an API fetch function in the stack navigator. I also do not want to call the API fetch function inside the screen. How can I do this?

**ScreenA**

```
const ScreenA = () => {
  return (
    <CardA
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.push("ScreenB", {
          name: "Jack",
        })
      }
    />
  );
};
```

**ScreenB**

```
const ScreenB = () => {
    const { job } = React.UseContext(IThemeContext);
    return (
      console.log(job);
    ) 
}
```

**StackNavigator**

```
type AppStackRoutes = {
  ScreenA: undefined;
  ScreenB: {name: string};
}

const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppStackRoutes>();


const MainStackNavigator = ({ route }) => {
   const [job, setJob] = useState(String);

   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setJob(
        await fetchAccounts(route.params.name) // from screenA
      );
    };
    fetchAPI();
  }, [setJob]);

  return (
   <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ job }}>
    <AppStack.Navigator>
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="ScreenA"
        component={ScreenA}
      />
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="ScreenB"
        component={ScreenB}
      />
    /AppStack.Navigator>
   </ThemeContext.Provider
  )

}
```

Comment: I don't think this `MainStackNavigator` will have access to any routing context below it in the ReactTree. In other words I think only the `AppStack.Navigator` it's rendering has that data. Is there an issue with just letting `ScreenB` access the param and issue the side-effect? You could probably abstract the API logic into a React context that is accessible by `ScreenB` is you are just wanting to move it out of the component.

Comment: I want to load the data from the API before `ScreenB` is displayed for a smoother experience.

Comment: Can you manage that in the `ScreenB` component with some [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)?

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: In most cases you conditionally render a loading indicator or something similar while the API request is made in an `useEffect` hook. When the data is fetched and state is updated, swap what is being conditionally rendered, i.e. now you display the JSX you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `route.params` will only be accessible in the screen to which you have passed them to during navigation. Thus, you cannot access them in `MainStackNavigator`.

Since you do not want to do this inside the screen and it seems that you need to use the same functionality in various different screens, you could define a `hook` that takes care of this.

```js
const useJob = (name) => {
    const [job, setJob] = useState()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
           const accounts = await fetchAccounts(name)
           setJob(accounts)
        }
        fetchAPI();
    }, [setJob])

    return {
         job,
    }
}
```

In order to render nothing until the data has been fetched, you can conditionally render nothing.

```js
const ScreenB = ({route}) => {
    const { job } = useJob(route.params.name)

    console.log(job);

    return (
      <>
       {job ? <View> .. whatever </View> : null}
      </>
    ) 
}
```